"Redundant 'await' for a non-promise type" warning in WebStorm for async function
I'm working on a Node.js project with WebStorm, and I'm getting a warning when hovering over a line of code that uses await to call an asynchronous function.
Context:
The code itself works perfectly, but WebStorm displays this warning:
Redundant 'await' for a non-promise type

This occurs when I use await with an asynchronous function that I defined myself. However, if I remove the await, the code breaks, but stops indicating the warning.
Here’s a simplified example of the code (sensitive information has been removed):
// authUtils.js
const axios = require("axios");

exports.getAccessToken = async (provider, clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUri) => {
    if (provider === "github") {
        const response = await axios.post(
            'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
            { client_id: clientId, client_secret: clientSecret, code },
            { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } }
        );
        return response.data.access_token;
    } else if (provider === "linkedin") {
        const response = await axios.post(
            'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken',
            null,
            {
                params: {
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    code,
                    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
                    client_id: clientId,
                    client_secret: clientSecret,
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            }
        );
        return response.data.access_token;
    }
};

Then, in my controller:
const { getAccessToken } = require('./authUtils');

exports.githubCallback = async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.query;
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken("github", clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUri);
        // Other stuff here...
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error during callback:", err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal error" });
    }
};

What I’ve tried:

If I remove await in const accessToken = await getAccessToken(...), the code breaks, indicating that await is required.
I’ve confirmed that getAccessToken is declared with async and uses await internally for HTTP calls, so it should indeed return a promise.

Question:
Why does WebStorm show this "Redundant 'await' for a non-promise type" warning? Is there a way to resolve this warning without removing await, which is definitely needed here?

Does it show the correct parameter list for the function?

Yes, WebStorm does display the correct parameter list for getAccessToken when hovering over it, and it recognizes each parameter individually (provider, clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUri). Despite this, the "Redundant 'await' for a non-promise type" warning still appears, even though getAccessToken is an async function.

This seems like a WS bug.
